# How to transform <a href="#"></a> to <%= link_to %> with css?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

How to transform (a href)  to <%= link_to %>?

**This code is work, but I don't need in it.**

```
<li><a href="users"><span>User</span></a></li>
```

**I need to rails code with <%= link_to %>. But I want that styles weren't gone.**

```
<li><%= link_to user_path %></li>
```

**style**

```
#mainNav a:active{
        top:1px;
    }
    #mainNav a:hover span ,
    #mainNav li.active span {
        background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);

        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0, rgb(71,83,101)),
            color-stop(1, rgb(123,145,177))
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to output in `erb` exactly what you have in your original `html`, you could use the following:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to user_path do %>
    <span>User</span>
  <% end %> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update it:-

```
<li id="mainNav"><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
```

**style**

```
#mainNav a:active{
        top:1px;
    }
    #mainNav a:hover ,
    #mainNav li.active {
        background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);

        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0, rgb(71,83,101)),
            color-stop(1, rgb(123,145,177))
        )
    }
```

Comment: I think, `#mainNav` not for `li` tag.